# is it possible to generate a graph in Visual Studio Online to show coders' contributions?

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops

Question is pretty much explained in the title. Did a project with version control in Visual Studio Online. Can I make a graph that shows one coders' amount of contributions and/or lines of code versus others? I know I could do so with GitHub, but can't seem to find it on VSO. This is a low priority question, so no need to break your back over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, if it's OK to use tools outside Visual Studio Online. The [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) supports VSO and can provide interesting reports about the contributions.

[image: Power BI]

The whole procedure is best described on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/04/gain-understanding-and-insights-into-projects-in-visual-studio-online-with-power-bi.aspx). But here's the main points:

1. Select Services - Visual Studio Online - Connect
2. Connect to your project
3. Power BI will import the data

Also Scott Hanselman's post about [.NET CoreCLR & PowerBI](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNETCoreCLRIsNowOpenSourceSoIRanTheGitHubRepoThroughMicrosoftPowerBI.aspx) may contain useful information.

Another option is to use offline tools. If your repository's source control is GIT, you can just checkout the branch and run some analytics over it. For example, you can use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) and then select "Show log" - Statistics for a graph like this:

[image: TortoiseGIT Statistics]

Comment: I can't find that option in tortoise git